# azure static files missing/ wrong MIME

Tags: django, linux, azure

Django website deployed to Azure (F1 - free subscription) Linux, all static files are missing/ not rendered. Even the files from admin which are not changed. Locally works fine, I've googled around tried to upload without VS code etc. still does not work.

Source code of app - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/python-docs-hello-django

Tutorial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=bash&pivots=python-framework-django

Deployed via Azure CLI, any pointers I would gladly take.

P.S. Templates dir and HTML files are fine/ loaded correctly, images from static are also missing.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my problem was new install + `whitenoise`, `requirements.txt` for Azure, following the approach and settings file in the video below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6Wyk9q2JM0&list=RDCMUCsMica-v34Irf9KVTh6xx-g&start_radio=1&t=302s

Github project - https://github.com/microsoft/beginners-django